# Find expression for : $ S_n =\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{i^4+i^2+1} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to find a formula for the sum of this series using its general term.
How to do it?

**Series**
$$
S_n = \underbrace{1/3 + 2/21 + 3/91 + 4/273 + \cdots}_{n \text{ terms}}
$$

**General Term**

$$
S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{i^4+i^2+1}
$$

Comment: I changed n\ \mbox{terms} to n\text{ terms}.  The mismatch in sizes of fonts resulted from use of an incorrect method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using partial fractions, we get $\dfrac{i}{i^4+i^2+1} = \dfrac{\tfrac{1}{2}}{i^2-i+1} - \dfrac{\tfrac{1}{2}}{i^2+i+1}$.

Thus, $S_n = \displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\dfrac{i}{i^4+i^2+1} = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{i^2-i+1} - \dfrac{1}{i^2+i+1}$.

Since $(i+1)^2-(i+1)+1 = i^2+i+1$, this sum telescopes to $S_n = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right)$.

Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ gives $S = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: thank you so much,but i have one doubt ,in which cases can i apply partial fraction to calculate sum?

Comment: Anytime you have a rational function (whose numerator has a smaller degree than its denominator), you can always try using partial fractions. Whether or not it will lead to a solution depends on the particular problem.

Comment: okay thank you for your help :)

Comment: Note that the factorisation $i^4+i^2+1=(i^2+i+1)(i^2-i+1)$ comes easily if you notice that $(i^2-1)(i^4+i^2+1)=i^6-1=(i^3+1)(i^3-1)=(i+1)(i^2-i+1)(i-1)(i^2+i+1)$

Answer (score 6):

Use partial fractions,

$$ \frac{i}{i^4+i^2+1} = \frac{1}{2(i^2-i+1)}-\frac{1}{2(i^2+i+1)} $$

Answer (score 4):

Write it out:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i}{i^4 + i^2 + 1}
&=& \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left( \frac{2}{4i^2 - 4i + 4}
  - \frac{2}{4i^2 + 4i + 4}\right)\\
&=&  \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left( \frac{2}{\Big(2i-1\Big)^2 + 3}
  - \frac{2}{\Big( 2i + 1\Big)^2 + 3}\right)\\
&=&  \frac{2}{\Big( 2 - 1\Big)^2 + 3} + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left( \frac{2}{\Big(2i+1\Big)^2 + 3}
  - \frac{2}{\Big( 2i + 1\Big)^2 + 3}\right)\\
&=& \frac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Mind to give reason for downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote you. But I think you posted the solution AFTER other users. I think they care about "speed" + "accuracy"....next time...

Comment: Well - that is the problem when you reply a post and in the mean time you watch the worldcup so you are late with the final result....

Thanks for the tip / advice!!

Comment: I downvoted because the question was to find $S_n$ not $S_\infty$. xx

Comment: @ user2584283 I think the OP asks for (a formula for) the sum of the series.

Comment: If you look at the question's edit history, you will see that at one time, it asked for the sum of the infinite series, not just the first $n$ terms.

Answer (score 1):

Set $$\color{blue}{a_k=  \frac{1}{k^2 -k +1} \implies a_{k+1}=  \frac{1}{(k+1)^2 -k } =\frac{1}{k^2+ k +1}} $$

But since $ (k^2 -k +1)(k^2 +k +1) =k^4 +k^2 +1$ we have,

$$ a_{k+1} -a_k = \frac{1}{k^2 +k +1}-  \frac{1}{k^2 -k +1} = \frac{2k}{(k^2 -k +1)(k^2 +k +1)} =\frac{2k}{k^4 +k^2 +1}$$

Then

$$a_n-a_0 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k+1} -a_k=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k}{k^4 +k^2 +1} $$